# Best Hosted VM Provider

Tags: virtualization, hosting

We have some boxes at a reputable (expensive) hosting company.

They don't offer a simple/flexible VM solution.

All I want is the ability to create CentOS VMs (mainly) to host our (mostly) static sites (corporate etc), maintaining the big boxes for more traffic/DB intensive services.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [Linode](http://www.linode.com/index.cfm) and [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/) with great success.

I've also discovered recently [Mosso](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers) which might be interesting depending on target usage. It's interesting to know it's owned by Rackspace and so is Slicehost. Mosso (now called Rackspace Cloud it seems) offers a really simple interface for creating virtual machines, similar to [Amazon's EC2 offer](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).

All of these let you choose from a range of distro and give you complete root access to configure the server as you want. Support for Linode and Slicehost has been great although my experience has been even better with the latter.

Finally, you can also have a [dedicated server](http://iweb.com/products/) at iWeb (amongst others) for pretty cheap where you don't need to take care of the hardware itself. They offer a wide-range of support package too if needed. If you really want to use virtual machines, you could install [Xen](http://www.xen.org/) on a dedicated machine and manage as many VMs as the hardware can handle.

Comment: +1 for Slicehost - great friendly customer support by genuine people, pretty average price and a nice web interface that while slightly rustic, is perfectly functional and can be accessed by an API, which could be handy and cost-cutting if you want to grow your services in real time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a fan of linode - http://www.linode.com/

Comment: me too, but they don't host virtual machines... they host VPSes

Comment: "virtual machine", "VPS", that's semantics. It's a matter of usage requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Slicehost

Comment: Forgot to mention that one advantage of Slicehost over Linode is that you can get free monitoring from Cloudkick. I don't know if Linode support is coming or not but currently Cloudkick supports: AWS, RackspaceCloud and Slicehost.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I've hosted virtual machines with http://www.melbourne.co.uk/ and have really liked their level of service so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get cheaper prices than http://www.prgmr.com

They have very good, personal support as well. They've been very helpful with performance issues I had from ordering too small of a machine initially.

My blog is hosted there, and I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Also depends if you want a dedicated solution or a shared solution.  If dedicated (not on shared hardware with other customers) VM's you would want to look into a hosting provider which will build your own infrastructure and maintain it.  Cost of course is not cheap for these, I know a few good ones that can do either.