# Hosting provider that allows you to host your own VM image?

Tags: hosting, virtual-machines, freebsd

I've already looked at the ['Best Hosted VM Provider'](https://serverfault.com/questions/41037/best-hosted-vm-provider) question and checked the recommendations there, but I seem to have slightly odd requirements.

Basically, I am looking for a host that allows me to host a VM image I supply (FreeBSD, which most of the suggested hosters don't support, they only seem to support various Linuxes) instead of one of their standard images. I'm a long time BSD user and have had colo BSD servers in the past so I'm pretty sure that i don't need much in the way of software support, but I'd basically like to run my server on managed hardware without having to rent the whole server. For the usage I have that would way OTT as we're talking a couple of small apps with very few users, a couple of blogs and (most importantly) email hosting for about 6-10 domains with moderate traffic levels.

Oh, and reliability trumps cost to a certain extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that RootBSD (http://www.rootbsd.net/) will work with you.  I know that Verio offers FreeBSD VPS hosting, but I think they only host jails.

Comment: I ended up just getting a hosting plan from RootBSD and transfer the configurations over.

Answer (score 2):

I host my FreeBSD image at Opus One (http://www.opus1.com/). They are a long-lived small ISP with a pretty impressive setup in their own facility. I had been on a pizza box with them for years, but have just transitioned to their VMware cloud. If you read Network World reviews, you'll know Joel Snyder's name. Highly recommended.